# How should I make my action ignore validation for one property?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I have database with 2 tables, Expenses and Categories. I have 2 controllers for both with lists and create/delete actions. Expense model has property of type Category(model for Categories table).
I wanted to make dropdown list for create modal in Expenses list.

This is dropdown list:

```
    <label asp-for="Expense.Category.Name" class="control-label"></label>
<select asp-for="Expense.Category.Id" style="height:38px;" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Categories,"Id","Name"))"></select>
```

When I choose item from dropdown list it passes Id of this item(Category) to the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult CreateOrEdit(int id, [Bind("Id,Amount,Category,Description,Date")] Expense expense)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (id == 0)
                {
                    _expenseRepository.Add(expense);
                }
                else
                {
                    _expenseRepository.Update(expense);
                }


                return Json(new { isValid = true, html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "_ViewAll", _expenseRepository.GetAllExpenses()) });
            }
            else
            {
                CreateOrEditViewModel viewModel = new CreateOrEditViewModel()
                {
                    Expense = expense,
                    Categories = _expenseRepository.GetCategoryList()
                };
                return Json(new { isValid = false, html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "CreateOrEdit", viewModel) });
            }
        }
```

Problem is, when it passes Id, this Expense expense model has Category with the same Id but property Name is null. And when Category model has Name field required it acts like I want to create new category and ModelState.IsValid is false because of that. On the other hand when I wanted to manually choose both Id and Name it was adding Expense to the database but in the same it created new category with new Id but with Name = Id of the name I chose.

I don't know what's going on here so I thought maybe I should make this action somehow ignore validation for this Category or viewModel for this only.

CreateOrEdit View modal if needed. I don't know what more to show because I have no idea how this should be fixed, I can post more if someone needs. Thanks in advance.

```
@model CreateOrEditViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    Layout = null;
}

<style>
    span {
        color: white;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form asp-action="CreateOrEdit" asp-route-id="@Model.Expense.Id" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);" autocomplete="off">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Expense.Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Expense.Amount" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="amountinput" asp-for="Expense.Amount" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Expense.Amount"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Expense.Category.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                        @*<select asp-for="Category" style="height:38px;" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoryList,"Name","Name"))"></select>*@
                        @*<select asp-for="Expense.Category" style="height:38px;" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Ctg>()"></select>*@
                        <select asp-for="Expense.Category.Id" style="height:38px;" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Categories,"Id","Name"))"></select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Expense.Category.Id"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Expense.Date" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input id="dateinput" asp-for="Expense.Date" style="height:38px;" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Expense.Date"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Expense.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Expense.Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Expense.Description"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


@if (Model.Expense.Id == 0)
{
    <script>
    // Date format: 17.07.2021 10:50:20
    @*$("#dateinput").val(@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");*@
    $("#amountinput").val("");
    </script>
}


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using your DB Entities as ViewModels which is not a good practice. Ideally your view models don't reference any entities at all. This is most probably the cause of your concern

Comment: I don't know iif I understand correctly. For example this CreateOrEditViewModel has 
public Expense Expense { get; set; }
public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
So I shouldn't use this Expense Expense here if it is my main model for db?

Comment: Yes. Your view model should not directly reference those Entities. Having a POCO model would be ideal.